# Is there a way to print out two different arrays in two columns in Excel?

Tags: java, arrays, excel, eclipse

When I try to print the second array "Object columnB []" in the same "sheet" in the excel file, then the first array disappears? Is there any way to solve this easily? I need both because the first array is "fixed". And the second array should be copied several times as there are different contestants

```java
    package sprint2;
    
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
    
    public class ExcelTest {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
            // Create workbook in .xls format
            Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            // For .xslx workbooks use XSSFWoorkbok();
            // Create Sheets
            Sheet sh = workbook.createSheet("Decathlon");
            Sheet sh2 = workbook.createSheet("Heptathlon");
            // cell.setCellValue("some string");
    
            // Values for Column A for Decathlon
            Object columnA[][] = { { "Name" }, 
                                   { "Number" }, 
                                   { "" }, 
                                   { "Event 1" }, 
                                   { "Event 2" }, 
                                   { "Event 3" },
                                   { "Event 4" }, 
                                   { "Event 5" }, 
                                   { "DAY 1 TOTAL" }, 
                                   { "DAY 1 PLACE" }, };
            // Create Cells and Column A for Decathlon
            int rowCount = 0;
            for (Object emp[] : columnA) {
                Row row = sh.createRow(rowCount++);
                int columnCount = 0;
                for (Object value : emp) {
                    Cell cell = row.createCell(columnCount++);
    
                    if (value instanceof String)
                        cell.setCellValue((String) value);
                    if (value instanceof Integer)
                        cell.setCellValue((Integer) value);
                    if (value instanceof Boolean)
                        cell.setCellValue((Boolean) value);
    
                }
            }
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Values for Column B for Decathlon
    
            Object columnB[][] = { { "Calvin hall" }, 
                                   { 100 }, 
                                   { "RESULT", "SCORE" }, 
                                   { "E1 Result", "E1 Score" },
                                   { "E2 Result", "E2 Score" }, 
                                   { "E3 Result", "E3 Score" }, 
                                   { "E4 Result", "E4 Score" },
                                   { "E5 Result", "E5 Score" }, 
                                   { "D1 TOTAL" }, 
                                   { "D1 PLACE" }, };
            // Create Row and Column B for Decathlon
            int rowCount1 = 0;
            for (Object emp1[] : columnB) {
                Row row1 = sh.createRow(rowCount1++);
                int columnCount1 = 1;
                for (Object value1 : emp1) {
                    Cell cell1 = row1.createCell(columnCount1++);
    
                    if (value1 instanceof String)
                        cell1.setCellValue((String) value1);
                    if (value1 instanceof Integer)
                        cell1.setCellValue((Integer) value1);
                    if (value1 instanceof Boolean)
                        cell1.setCellValue((Boolean) value1);
    
                }
            }
            // Merge cells on row 1,2,9,10 Column B and C
            sh2.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 1, 2));
            sh2.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 1, 2));
            sh2.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(8, 8, 1, 2));
            sh2.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(9, 9, 1, 2));
            // Autosize Decathlon-columns
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                sh.autoSizeColumn(i);
            }
    
            try {
                // Write the output to file
                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\snick\\Desktop\\Exceltest.xls");
                workbook.write(output);
                output.close();
                workbook.close();
                System.out.println("Excel-file is Completed");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-create the same row when you iterate over object B. Replace

```java
Row row1  = sh.createRow(rowCount1++);
```

with

```java
Row row1 = sh.getRow(rowCount1++);
```

However, you must be sure that this row really exists, that is columnA array has at least the same amount of rows as columnB array. Otherwise you need to use createRow when rowCount1 is larger than columnA.length. You can try to `getRow` first and if it returns null - use `createRow` to add a new one.

Similar problem is with the `createCell` calls in the second loop.

Comment: Thanks so much! Now it works as I thought :D